# Array , Esse código acima , não apesenta erro algum e quando eu abro ele :

Tags: php

http://prntscr.com/jjnyib

Esse código acima , não apesenta erro algum e quando eu abro ele :

http://prntscr.com/jjo0ga

Comment: Poste os códigos, não os prints

Comment: Se não houvesse erro algum, não exibiria erros.

Answer (score 2):

O erro apontado se refere à variável "$mel" que não existe, a que você declarou é "$meal".

Comment: Isso mesmo o uso da variável declarada está errada.

Answer (score 0):

Detalhe, além do erro de digitação da variável, como já mencionou o [Valdir Silva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/107870/valdir-silva), parece que esses `foreach` estão **trocado**s... Pois você define, por exemplo, a variável `$dish` no segundo `foreach`, mas o usa no primeiro (?). Tente **trocar** de lugar os `foreach`.. Creio que funcione...

Outro detalhe, a variável `$price` e `$value` estão trocadas, inverta elas também. E a variável deve ser `$meals` e não `$meal`.

Está funcionando, pode fazer o teste:

```
    <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title> Loop with Foreach()</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php
      $meals = array('Walnut bun' => 1,
                     'Cashew Nuts and White Mushroons' => 4.95,
                     'Dried Mulberries' =>3.00,
                     'Eggplant with Chili Sauce' => 6.50
                   );

              foreach ($meals as $dish => $value){

                $meals[$dish] = $meals[$dish]*2;

              };


              foreach ($meals as $key => $price){

                printf("The new price of %s is \$%.2f\n", $dish, $price);
                echo "<br>";
              }

    ?>

    </body>
   </html>
```